# How are Chi Square probabilities calculated?

Tags: probability, statistics

What steps would one follow to calculate the values in a Chi Square probability table such as https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html?

Say you had 15 degrees of freedom and wanted *p* to be 0.105, could someone please write a step-by-step process for getting from those two numbers to the probability value?

Comment: What do you mean by $p$ , is this the critical value?

Comment: I may have confused terminology: by p I mean the x axis on the page linked above. Is that not used to denote probability of chance? My maths is very rusty and I haven't touched Chi Square since A Level Psy :)

Comment: If you wanted what you call p = 0.10, then the table has value 22.307. But there is no column headed 0.105, and I don't think linear interpolation works well in chi-squared tables. Statistical software gives 22.108 for p = 0.105. That means value 22.108 cuts off probability 0.105 from the right-hand tail of the density curve of Chisq(df=15). However, I have to say I can't think of any legitimate procedure that would lead to this question, and I think you might be on a wrong track. How about telling us what problem you're actually trying to solve and showing us how your question arises.

Comment: I'm creating software for multivariant testing, so there may be any number of degrees of freedom and the user may want any p value. I'd like to be able to calculate the critical value either on-the-fly or perhaps in bulk and cached somewhere. Anything other than packaging a big table :) So how does one go from knowing the x and y values in the table linked above to calculating the value where they meet? How are these tables generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is excellent open source software to which you could link
or which you might use as a guide. For large df there are good
approximations. Much of your approach will be governed by
whether you need only tail probabilities and how many places of
accuracy you need. Google 'approximate CDF of chi-squared'
and similar phrases to tap into rich literature on this topic.

IMSL maintains a library of compiled or compilable FORTRAN
code of well-vetted procedures for a wide variety of commonly
used distributions. I don't know what the licensing arrangements
are. And there are sources of excellent open source code.

All of this is to say that re-inventing this wheel, by now
very well refined and engineered by experts, seems a waste of time.
Nevertheless, here are a couple of additional observations.

Numerical integration works OK in many cases:
For example, if $Q \sim Chisq(df = 30)$, the R code
`qchisq(.95, 30)` returns `143.77297`, and `pchisq(43.77, 30)`
returns `0.9499692`.
If you mean P-value in the usual sense of statistical inference,
the P-value corresponding to an observed value 43.77 would
be `1 - pchisq(43.77, 30)` or `0.05003083`, just on the
borderline of significance at the 5% level. So it is essentially
the CDF you'd want to compute by numerical integration.

Representing the easily computable density function by `dchisq`,
we'd have the R code.

```
 grid = seq(0, 43.77, len = 10^5)
 height = dchisq(grid, 30)
 mean(height)*43.77
 ## 0.949962
```

Which gives the correct answer to reasonable accuracy. (Refinements
are possible and worthwhile, but this gives the central idea.)

Another approach, widely used in these days of cheap memory,
is to include a detailed chi-square table for reference.
Interpolation works well over short increments; not at all
between df's.

I am reasonably knowledgeable about what is behind the 
code of the software I use regularly--in a general sense, but certainly not an expert on
the technical details. Going further would put me at serious risk of 'telling' you more.
than I know.